# How to do a weighted combine of two tensors with trainable weighting?

Tags: tensorflow, keras

I'd like to have a layer that takes two inputs of the same dimension, `A` and `B` and generates an output `C = A + w*B` where `w` is a trainable scalar.  In my case, `A` and `B` are from a 1D CNN so have shape (batch, time, features).  Is there a way to make an existing layer perform this function, or do I need to code up a custom layer?

Comment: you should define what is `w`... variable is to vague... is it a scalar? a vector that get's multiplied with all the feature of B? what's its size?

Comment: Scalar.  Question edited.

Comment: Thank you… you need a custom layer since you want to have “a state”, if you give me an hour i’ll post an answer with the code

Answer (score 5):

Since you have a state, you want to use subclassing, heres a possible implementation:

```
class WeightedSum(K.layers.Layer):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(**kwargs)
        self.W = self.add_weight("W", shape=[1], dtype=tf.float32, trainable=True)
    def call(self, inputs, *args, **kwargs):
        A,B = inputs
        return A + self.W*B
```

If you want to check that W is trainable, you can see it from here:

```
input = K.layers.Input(shape=10)
x1 = K.layers.Dense(10, trainable=False)(input)
x2 = K.layers.Dense(10, trainable=False)(input)
sum = WeightedSum()([x1, x2])
res = K.layers.Dense(1, trainable=False)(sum)

model = K.models.Model(inputs = [input], outputs = [res])
model.compile(K.optimizers.Adam(), loss="binary_crossentropy")
model.fit(np.random.random((100, 10)), np.random.choice([0,1], (100,)), epochs=10)
```

Output:

```
Epoch 1/10
4/4 [==============================] - 0s 9ms/step - loss: 6.5532
Epoch 2/10
4/4 [==============================] - 0s 5ms/step - loss: 6.5522
Epoch 3/10
4/4 [==============================] - 0s 5ms/step - loss: 6.5513
Epoch 4/10
4/4 [==============================] - 0s 5ms/step - loss: 6.5504
Epoch 5/10
4/4 [==============================] - 0s 4ms/step - loss: 6.5500
Epoch 6/10
4/4 [==============================] - 0s 5ms/step - loss: 6.5491
Epoch 7/10
4/4 [==============================] - 0s 5ms/step - loss: 6.5484
Epoch 8/10
4/4 [==============================] - 0s 5ms/step - loss: 6.5479
Epoch 9/10
4/4 [==============================] - 0s 5ms/step - loss: 6.5472
Epoch 10/10
4/4 [==============================] - 0s 5ms/step - loss: 6.5466
```

and you see that even though all the other layers are not trainable, the loss decreases (since W is optimized)

About the fact that the 2 vector comes from a 1D conv, should not matter (until they have the same size, or a compatible one)

Comment: Thanks, a custom layer like this is an option.  I was just wondering if an existing layer could be repurposed.  For example, a CNN with a kernel size of 1.  I know that doesn't work in my case, but something like that.

Comment: @Mastiff you probably can do something like this: `tf.keras.layers.Add()([A, tf.keras.layers.Conv1D(filters=1, kernel_size=(1,1))(B)])`, but convolution is not too lightweight as a operation, it's sort of implemented as a loop, probably a scalar/matrix product is much faster

Comment: Problem with that is that I'd only have one feature layer after the conv, I think.  So it wouldn't add to A.

Comment: @Mastiff no, the thing you have to fix is the number of filters. in other words, the 1D conv layer that I'm creating, should have as many filters as A: ```tf.keras.layers.Add()([A, tf.keras.layers.Conv1D(filters="same as A", kernel_size=(1,1))(B)])```

Comment: In that case there would be more than one weight though, right?

Comment: @Mastiff mayyyyybe you are actually right... at that point, you can use 1 filter, add a Lambda layer that uses `tf.repeat` over the main axis a number of times equal to the channel of A... but I think that 5 lines of custom layer are way better at this point ahah